# Unable to reset MySQL Server Root Password

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

I tried to start MYSQL in safe mode to reset the root password, but getting the below error.

I had mysql server installed on my mac, yesterday i encountered some error where it was repeatedly shutting down automatically. However i wasn't able to connect to server using command line as it was erroring out mentioning the root password was wrong. Though I was able to connect using mysql workbench.

I reinstalled SQL Server and still not able to login using the new root password.

`sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables`

> 2019-10-23T10:13:40.361911Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
> 2019-10-23T10:13:40.362146Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
> 2019-10-23T10:13:40.362217Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.28) starting as process 4763 ...
> 2019-10-23T10:13:40.365571Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql-5.7.28-macos10.14-x86_64/data/ is case insensitive
> 2019-10-23T10:13:40.365648Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
>
> 2019-10-23T10:13:40.365676Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
>
> 2019-10-23T10:13:40.365690Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
> 2019-10-23T10:13:40.365844Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete

Comment: Maybe it has gone back to its default password installation. Have you looked into that? Try with empty password.

Comment: It did display a default password for using this, tried that as well as the default password. Still its failing.